# Current in a wire and a ring above it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

I have this simple question, imagine the current is flowing in a wire (black line) to the right and there's a copper ring above it, in what direction (clock wise or counter clock wise) and why current will flow in the ring? All of the ring's points are in the same plane as wire's. See photo for visual explanation. Thanks.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Use right hand thumb rule.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I don't know how knowing magnetic field direction will help me.

Comment: Is the current in the straight wire constant?

Comment: @garyp Yes, it is not changing.

Comment: an induced current can only appear is there is a change in the magnetic flux ring,  and this can only occur if the current is NOT constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to be a bit more specific. If you have a direct current in your wire and keep your set up stationary, you'll have absolutely no emf induced in the ring, and so no current will flow. This is because there would be no change in magnetic flux.

On the other hand, suppose there is AC current flowing. Then you have a change of magnetic flux through the ring. Faraday's law tells us that a change of magnetic flux through a surface induces an emf across the surface - in fact, it tells a bit more than this, but I'll spare those details. The presence of an emf will drive a current round the loop. It is Faraday's law that tells us that there will be a current in the ring.

Now, for the direction, we result to Lenz's Law. This states that the direction of the induced current is always so as to oppose the change in flux that caused it. Using the right hand rule for the wire, we can see that the magnetic field lines curl upwards and outwards (in a cylindrical fashion). This tells us that the current in the ring will have to be in a clockwise sense, because current in this direction will create a magnetic field that opposes the change of magnetic flux.

Comment: Thanks, looked up Lenz's Law more and everything makes sence now.